# Complex hierarchy problem in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, oop

I don't know if it is so complex like I say :P

This is the case use: I have a project with a lot of targets, and all use the same common code, but I create children class to use specific things. This is the spirit of object-oriented.

I have this hierarchy  in program

```
NSObject -> ClassA_level_1 -> ClassA_level_2
NSObject -> ClassB_level_1 -> ClassB_level_2
```

**ClassB_level_1** have a variable `ClassA_level_1 *classA` so call function in level1 is no problem. The problem is that ClassB_level_1 have to call things in **ClassA_level_2** (NOT level 1) in some delegates function.

If in level_2 i can call **super** to get things in level_1, how can I do the opposite way? There are some tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you encounter this problem, you are most likely violating [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem). In OOP, a square is not a rectangle.

If you are not violating LSP, then `ClassB_level_1` should still not be calling anything in `ClassA_level_2`. `ClassB_level_2` should be where that special logic is implemented, and it should therefore know the class of its delegate, and be able to assert that the class is correct and then cast to it. That said, if you find yourself here, it's often because of a more basic architectural problem.

First, reconsider your problem in terms of protocols rather than classes. What functionality do you really need from this other object? Check it with a protocol and `respondsToSelector:` rather than by asserting some class.

Could `ClassB` be a factory for `ClassA` so that it always creates the correct helper object? Perhaps you should reconsider this as a [Class Cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34). When you find yourself creating complicated parallel hierarchies, often it's time to pull out [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and rethink your architecture. In particular, [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is often useful for problems that would otherwise lead to large parallel trees.

But if your design is correct, you just need to use `respondsToSelector:` to make sure your delegate responds to the method you want before calling it.

Comment: Very good explanation! This is exactly a square-rectangle problem :)